# pipelight: error downloading wine-flash-installer

Tags: 16.04, firefox, flash, pipelight

I've been trying to use pipelight to install Flash on Firefox so I can watch HBO Now. I am able to install Widevine and Silverlight without any issues but I get the following error in console when it tries to install Flash:

```
[install-dependency] ERROR: Downloading of wine-flash-installer failed multiple times. Please check:
[install-dependency]
[install-dependency]        * that your internet connection is working properly
[install-dependency]
[install-dependency]        * and that the plugin database is up-to-date. To update it just run:
[install-dependency]            sudo pipelight-plugin --update
[install-dependency]
[install-dependency]        If this doesn't help then most-likely the download URLs or checksums
[install-dependency]        have changed. We recommend to open a bug-report in this case.
[install-dependency] ERROR: Download of wine-flash-installer failed.
```

I have found multiple threads online from a couple years back which suggest to update pipelight to v0.2.8 but I am already using v0.2.8.2. I've run --update and --create-mozilla-plugins as well. Does anyone know how I can fix this error or download the necessary installer manually?

(using Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox 50.1.0)

edit; Also, the output of 'sudo pipelight-plugin --update' if it helps:

```
Resolving bitbucket.org (bitbucket.org)... 2401:1d80:1010::150, 104.192.143.3, 104.192.143.2, ...
Connecting to bitbucket.org (bitbucket.org)|2401:1d80:1010::150|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 29488 (29K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/tmp.2j7RyqWGg6’

/tmp/tmp.2j7RyqWGg6                     100%[==============================================================================>]  28.80K  --.-KB/s    in 0.03s   

2016-12-26 23:56:09 (1.03 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/tmp.2j7RyqWGg6’ saved [29488/29488]

gpg: Signature made Tue 01 Nov 2016 04:29:54 PM EDT using RSA key ID 1434FC73
gpg: Good signature from "Pipelight Dev Team (install-dependency) <webmaster@fds-team.de>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: CF23 08D4 3507 9A77 124E  01A2 83C7 3FB2 1434 FC73

Script dependency-installer is already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Adobe has recently resumed to provide Netscape flashplugin updates for linux, have you tried that?

Comment: Install the `adobe-flashplugin` package from Canonical Partner; please check out [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html).

Comment: Yeah, pipelight seems quite broken atm. Maybe try again in a couple of weeks in case someone still cares to fix

Comment: This may be of interest, as in it's pretty much dead - http://pipelight.net/

Comment: What a bummer. Looks like I'll have to rely on my Windows dual-boot until HBO abandons Flash (like everyone else has).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments on the top post (and pipelight.net) it looks like Pipelight has been discontinued so I'm not sure there's a solution.

An alternative, for those without access to another OS, is to install Firefox and Flash with Wine. I find this to work reasonably well.

Comment: Probably the best solution, I did rebuild pipelight-multi to install the current windows flash (24.0.0.0.186 as of a few days ago) & it seems ok but as the pipelight updater would obviously not work it would have to be redone every time there was a security update to flash, hardly worth the hassle. (or one would have to stick with their current version). If curious changes to source can be seen here - https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-prop/+files/pipelight-multi_0.2.8.2~ubuntu14.04.1_0.2.8.2~ubuntu14.04.2~ppa.diff.gz

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Right on. I think I had to use both libhal and pepperflash-freshplayer to get HULU to work if I remember correctly. I just saw that the OP had a downvote and was sort of defending them as somtimes it seems that wine ends up as a last resort when freshplayer and libhal don't work. I'll go ahead and clean up my comments here and delete them. Have fun!